# In Excel, how to change ordering of horizontal axis w/o shifting vertical axis

Tags: excel, axis

[Excel ordering of the horizontal axis shifts the vertical axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEyce.png)
I am not sure what is the best way to present this question. I have attached the image. I am trying to change the ordering of the horizontal axis so that the trend shows from earlier quarters to recent. When I click on the format axis, and check the reverse order box (as circled in the image), the direction of the trend shifts. But the Y axis shifts to the right. I would like the Y axis to stay at the original position. Is there a way to do it ? Many thanks and please let me know if more information/data is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the "Vertical axis crosses" setting on that same tab to "At maximum category".

edit: you should be able to just sort the source data as well

Comment: thanks. "At maximum category" gave the desired result.